# Exactly what does the decimal point in the following number mean?

Tags: significant-figures

Exactly what does the decimal point in the following number mean?

$$2. \cdot 10^{11}$$

It's not followed by any digits. Has it something to do with significant figures?
My guess is it has exactly one significat figure i.e $2$.
The dot means the number ends at $2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, the indication is that there is 1 significant figure in the specified number.

Comment: Thanks. It was on a question's solution and I thought it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

Certain softwares use this notation to show that the answer isn't exact, so 2. means that it is *very close* to 2, but is *not* 2 exactly.